# Graph recovery from pairwise-common neighborhoods

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Define the *common neighborhood* of two vertices $u$ and $v$ of a simple undirected graph as the set $N(u,v)=N(u)\cap N(v)$. For a simple bipartite graph $G=(U,V,E)$, define the *pairwise-common neighborhoods set* as $\{N(u_1,u_2):u_1\not=u_2\in U∧N(u_1,u_2)≠∅\}$.

1. Is it possible to recover a bipartite $G$ if given only its pairwise-common neighborhoods set? Assume $G$ connected and degree greater or equal than 2 for all vertices.
2. Is there an efficient algorithm that constructs *some* bipartite graph with a given pairwise-common neighborhoods set, or halts if one does not exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121282/discussion-between-smapers-and-delete000).

Comment: As stated (with the set given as input, without multiplicities), the answer to question 1 is no.  Given just the pairwise-common neighborhood set, without multiplicities, you can't distinguish the complete bipartite graphs $K_{n, 2}$ from $K_{n', 2}$ for any integers $n, n'\ge 2$.